# What are the appropriate lattice constant , pseudopotential and atomic positions for BCC Na with 0 kbar pressure? (for Quantum ESPRESSO)

Tags: quantum-espresso, pseudopotentials

BCC Na is the most stable structure of Na, and the most stable structure gives the pressure around 0 kbar.
But a paper named "*Structure stability in the simple element sodium under pressure*"  says the lattice constant for bcc Na is 4.2908 Angstrom for ambient conditions.
When I calculate with lattice constant 4.2908 Angstrom and NC LDA type pseudopotential, which is  "http://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/upf_files/Na.pw-mt_fhi.UPF", I get pressure 121.71 kbar.

I am attaching my input files below.
It will be a great help if anyone suggests to me the appropriate pseudopotential and atomic positions for BCC Na with 0 kbar pressure by using the lattice constant 4.2908 Angstrom?

```
  &CONTROL
  calculation = 'scf'
  etot_conv_thr =   2.0000000000d-05
  forc_conv_thr =   1.0000000000d-04
  outdir = './out/'
  prefix = 'aiida'
  pseudo_dir = '.'
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  verbosity = 'low'
/
&SYSTEM
  degauss =   1.4699723600d-02
  ecutrho =  700
  ecutwfc =  70
  celldm=8.108453484
  ibrav = 3
  nat = 2
  nosym = .false.
  ntyp = 1
  occupations = 'smearing'
  smearing = 'gaussian'
/
&ELECTRONS
  conv_thr =   4.0000000000d-10
  electron_maxstep = 80
  mixing_beta =   4.0000000000d-01
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Na     22.98977 Na.pw-mt_fhi.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Na       0.000000000  -0.000000000   0.000000000
Na       0.500000000   0.500000000   0.5000000000 
K_POINTS automatic
9 9 9 0 0 0
```

Comment: Ambient condition include temp as well. You can also try other way round, Get your relaxed equilibrium lattice parameter first and then use that relaxed lattice parameter as you input for second calculations. In second calculation apply pressure of 1 atm and see what is lattice parameter at given pressure of 1 atm.

Comment: The paper you mention cites https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X56001790 for the structural parameters of Na. It's worth noting that said paper finds that a mixed bcc+hcp low-temperature phase. (I also didn't see the number 4.2908 in that paper, so maybe it was published somewhere else... You can find a computed value for bcc Na in https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.220103)

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.34.4996 might be interesting as well